# How to get the 1-hr, 7-day and 1-month percentage changes of a stock with Google Finance/Sheets

Tags: arrays, date, google-sheets, google-finance, google-finance-api

I can currently get the `24hr percent change` of a stock in Google Sheets by:
`=GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOGL","changepct")`

How do I get the `1-hr`, `7-day` and `1-month` percent changes of a stock(or even a custom amount)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if by `1-hr` you mean change between this hour and previous hour then `1-hr` percent change is not possible to get by formula. could be doable via script where you would run a trigger every hour to log the values and then just compute the change with a simple formula.

`changepct` stands for "percentage change in price since the previous trading day's close" so to be precise it is not the `24-hr` unless you look at it at `16:00:00` when the closing happens. if you wish for a true `24-hr` then again, you need to resolve it with a script that will log the values on an hourly basis and compute the change with a simple time-moving formula

`7-day` and `1-month` are possible.

to calculate percentage change the formula is:

[image]

translated into a formula it would be:

```
=((GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOGL", "price")-INDEX(
   GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOGL", "price", TODAY()-6, TODAY()), 2, 2))/INDEX(
   GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOGL", "price", TODAY()-6, TODAY()), 2, 2))*100
```

[image]

---

```
=((GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOGL", "price")-INDEX(
   GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOGL", "price", TODAY()-29, TODAY()), 2, 2))/INDEX(
   GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOGL", "price", TODAY()-29, TODAY()), 2, 2))*100
```

[image]